# Android adaptative animations logic

Tags: android, animation, optimization

I search to create a set of class for my app that allow me adapt animations to the device capabilities.

I think of a scoring system (ex: 1 for the most inefficient devices and 5 for the most powerful) where different level corresponding to same animation but with different degree of computational calculation.

My approach consist to realize micro-benchmark at first start of app or regularly depend to different parameter like: timeout a bit too much regular, etc. I don't list in detail in what conditions launch this test.

I know some apps exist to show us devices features like Android System Info. I want to know if library exist for that or if someone know the best approach to achieve it (it could work with no rooted devices).

However if someone know library that could corresponding with entirety of this "project" it's preferable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [device-year-class](https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class) from Facebook. If I understand what you're looking for, this will allow you to figure out the capabilities of the device your app is running on.